# Nested functions with separate .mfiles error

Tags: matlab, function, nested

I'm trying to understanding scoping within Matlab and I'm a bit confused.  From what I have gleaned from the internet I know that if a variable is defined in the primary function the nested function will see that variable in its workspace.  For example

```
function test = myfun(x)

a = 1;


    function test = myfun2(x)

        test = x + a;

    end

test = x + myfun2(x);

end

>>myfun(1) 
  3 #Yay it worked.
```

However, if I break `myfun` and `myfun2` into separate .m files I get an error.  For example

#### myfun.m

```
function test = myfun(x)

a = 1;

test = x + myfun2(x);

end
```

#### myfun2.m

```
function test = myfun2(x)

test = x + a;

end

>>myfun(1)
Undefined function or variable 'a'.
```

What is up?  I have attempted to make `a` a global variable in the myfun.m file, however, this did not change matters.  The only way I can get around this is if I include `a` as an argument in `myfun2` which is something I would not like to do.

Comment: Why not make `a` an input argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each function in MATLAB has it's own local scope (or workspace as MATLAB calls it) consisting of the variables that you define within that function. The function can *only* see these variables and [does not have access to variables stored within other functions *or* the base workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html).

You are correct that [a nested function has access to the workspace of the parent](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#f4-73993) function which is why your first example works. When you create a separate m-file, however, `myfun2` is no longer a nested function. It is a stand-alone function with it's own isolated local scope.

The only (recommended) way of sending information between the various local scopes of the functions is [via input and output arguments to the functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html). The use of [global variables is discouraged](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html#f0-38470).

So for these two separate m-files, you would need to define input and output arguments for `myfun2` like the following.

**myfun.m**

```
function test = myfun(x)
    a = 1;
    test = x + myfun2(x, a);
end
```

**myfun2.m**

```
function test = myfun2(x, a)
    test = x + a;
end
```

Then you can call `myfun` as you expect.

```
>> myfun(1)
```

If you really *must* use globals, then you need to define the global variable [within ***all*** workspaces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html#f0-38470) that need access to it. So you would want to place the `global a` statement in *both* functions.